# Can't filter array returned from firebase in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

This is the html:

```
    <div ng-controller="FilterController as ctrl">
      <div>
    All entries:
    <span ng-repeat="entry in ctrl.array">{{entry.from}} </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    Entries that contain an "a":
    <span ng-repeat="entry in ctrl.filteredArray">{{entry.from}} </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my script:

```
angular.module('myApp', ["firebase"]).
  controller('FilterController', ['filterFilter', '$firebase', function(filterFilter,       $firebase) {
   var ref = new Firebase("https://******.firebaseio.com/");
   this.array = $firebase(ref).$asArray();
   this.filteredArray = filterFilter(this.array, 'a');
  }]);
```

The result from filteredArray is just empty. What have I done wrong? Many thanks for any insight.

Comment: could you please share the code of the 'filterFilter' function?

Comment: filterFilter is an inbuilt filter in angular for array, it's predefined. It works fine with a normal array, but not one returned from firebase.

Comment: no, it's not, you must have a service with a wrapper for the build-in one: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter , share the code of that wrapper

Comment: see this: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Comment: Yep, I've seen that, so? where is the 'filterFilter' function in the link that you just shared? Trust me: 'filterFilter' is not a build-in function in angularjs.

Comment: Yeah, Firebase always returns an object—even if you use the push functionalities to add items. You need to convert your object to an array. You can write a simple filter that'll do that. The function would be somethihng like: `function (obj) { return obj.keys(a).map(function(key){return a[key]}); }`

Comment: @Josep filterFilter is a thing: http://plnkr.co/edit/AQvgW0GLTzXyI5KlZAtI?p=preview

Comment: I believe AngularFire provides some special utilities for reading the objects as arrays so that Angular filtering is possible: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-arrays

Answer (score 0):

The data loads in an asynchronous manner. This is JavaScript 101 and you should probably spend a little time on asynchronous ops before you try to tackle Angular and Firebase.

Your filter call happens probably even before the request is sent to the server, thus the array is still empty.

You can use the $loaded method to wait for the initial data to be downloaded. However, your filtered results will still be static, circumventing the real-time capabilities.

```
this.array.$loaded(function() {
   console.log(this.array.length); // current length at time of loading
});
console.log(this.array.length); // 0, hasn't loaded yet
```

Generally, you should not be doing things like this at the code level, but instead letting Angular and Firebase work their magic; move it into the view:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in array | filter:searchText" />
```

If you find yourself trying to manipulate arrays in your controller to transform data, check out $extendFactory instead. But mostly, just leave it alone and bind it to scope, then let Angular take care of the rest.